# What is the quickest way to find all a_i for a_1^2+a_2^2+...a_n^2 = 1

Tags: matlab, math

This is a programming question I recently encounter in a math problem.

So given `n`, I want to find all the combinations of integers `a_i (1<=i<=n)` such that
`a_1^2+a_2^2+...a_n^2 = 1`

EDIT: Restrict the `a_i` to tenth decimal places (i.e. increments 0.01). For example, if `n = 3`, I will make `a_1 = 0.01`, `a_2 = 0.01`, `a_3 = sqrt(1-a_1^2-a_2^2);` then increment `a_2 = 0.02`, so on.

I can't do `n` nested for loop, because `n` could be a 10 digits number (exaggerated).

How do I do so?

Comment: Are the `a_i` real? Complex? Gaussian integers?

Comment: The equation you wrote down is that of a n-dimensional unit sphere.  As stated, there are an infinite number of points on this unit sphere.  So, can you elaborate?

Comment: `a_1 = 0.01...` Those integers look so real...

Comment: @Amadan Yea, I want them to be real integers

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a joke. There are (simply speaking) two kinds of numbers a computer can handle: integers (no decimal point, just 1, 2, 3...) and reals (with decimal point: 0.01, 4.0, 17.824...). A number can't be both real and an integer (you could say 4.0 and 4 are both, but computers wouldn't think so). The equation you wrote has no integral solutions except the trivial (1, 0, 0...), and an infinite number of real solutions.

Comment: @Amadan Can we think this as in Matlab when it handles floating point well, and I just want to have some approximation of c_i to the nearest 0.01...

Comment: This makes no sense. I am not sure whether this problem is properly adressed. As is said earlier, the equation written is the equation for a n-dimensional unit sphere. Given that the coefficients are integers, only the unit solution is possible. otherwise, each points is mapped to an element on the sphere. This means the exact solution to your is the one stated in your problem and nothing can be done to that. There is really no point in finding all the solutions since the equations is known. This is a complete waste of memory. Try instead to find a way to get a vector of values from the eq.

Comment: FYI finding a point on the hyper sphere may still best be done using `spherical` coordinates. Check on the internet how this is done. An example is [this paper](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~gaurav1/final%20paper.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to scale the problem
Make a list/array of integer squares
`Squares = {1, 4, 9, 16, .., 9801, 10000}`

Find combinations of N list values to make 10000. You can use dynamic programming to get solutions.
Example of possible combination for N=8:

```
9801+100+64+25+4+4+1+1
```

corresponds to rescaled numbers

```
0.99 0.1 0.08 0.05 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.01
```

Note that number of combinations will enormous big for large N values

Comment: Good luck in trying to reach a sum of 1 with these guys... (OP didn't mean integers in the common sense)